# A pointer to a combined interface - point to a class implementing one and extending from an implementation of the other

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have two interfaces:

```
class FirstInterface
{
    virtual int getId() const = 0;
};

class SecondInterface
{
    virtual void setId(int id) = 0;
};
```

This is a combined interface:

```
class CombinedInterface : public FirstInterface, public SecondInterface
{

};
```

This is a concrete class of first interface:

```
class FirstConcrete : public FirstInterface
{
    virtual int getId() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Now, this class **CompleteConcrete** should have the **CombinedInterface** but want to reuse the implementation of **FirstConcrete** at the same time.

```
class CompleteConcrete : public FirstConcrete, public SecondInterface
{
    virtual void setId(int id) { }
};

// This is wrong C++
// Cannot convert from CompleteConcrete * to CombinedInterface *
// CombinedInterface * combinedInterface = new CompleteConcrete();
```

This is not working of course. **Does anyone know a way to achieve this goal in C++ ??**

Comment: I can make this work using virtual inheritance, and one small tweak to the hierarchy. If you can make the rest of your stuff work with virtual inheritance, that would be one answer. If you don't know what virtual inheritance means, this will probably not work for you.

Comment: Do you really need `CombinedInterface` ?

Comment: You may use composition to reuse implementation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know what virtual inheritance is, I don't like the idea of having to use that technique but if it will achieve the goal with no serious side effects I'll use it. Please post your answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I need it. It's like a ReadInterface for Database, and a WriteInterface. Now I need to provide a pointer to a ReadWriteInterface to the Database. 
Some clients need just the ReadInterface .. Some need both.

Comment: @Jarod42 Composition will need to implement all the FirstInterface methods and delegate them to a member variable of type FirstConcrete Right? but this will not expose the protected members of FirstConcrete which may include caching and will be helpful to access them.

Comment: I think it would be nice if everyone posted their answers.

Comment: If you want to be compatible with ReadWriteInterface, you need to inherit ReadWriteInterface. There is no way around it. Just use virtual inheritance to inherit from pure abstract classes (interfaces). "I don't like it" is not a serious argument.

Comment: @n.m. I think you are right so as SamVarshavchik

Comment: I have a suggestion for the answer using virtual inheritance but I think I need someone to explain it more! I may be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the virtual-inheritance based solution that I mentioned in the comments:

```
class FirstInterface
{
    virtual int getId() const = 0;
};

class SecondInterface
{
    virtual void setId(int id) = 0;
};


class CombinedInterface : virtual public FirstInterface,
              virtual public SecondInterface
{

};

class FirstConcrete : virtual public FirstInterface
{
    virtual int getId() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class CompleteConcrete : virtual public FirstConcrete,
             virtual public CombinedInterface
{
    virtual void setId(int id) { }
};

void example()
{
    CombinedInterface * combinedInterface = new CompleteConcrete();
}
```

With virtual inheritance, the only change that's needed (besides the elephant in the room) is to have `CompleteConcrete` multiply-inherit from `CombinedInterface`, instead of `SecondInterface`. You can think of it this way: with `CompleteConcreate` in the picture, it now supports `CombinedInterface`, and not just the addition of `SecondInterface`.

Some frown on virtual inheritance. I don't. It's one of the unique features of C++, that no other high level language shared, TMK. It's a very powerful tool, and can solve certain problems that would be hard to solve in other ways. The two main disadvantages of virtual inheritance are:

1. Because it is so powerful, it can be easily misused, and lead to various problems.
2. If virtually-inherited classes have non-default constructors it quickly becomes painful, because every class that virtually inherits something is now responsible for constructing it.

But as long as virtual inheritance is used correctly, and the involved classes can take of constructing themselves, virtual inheritance is a useful tool.

P.S. I'll also mention one other alternative solution that just came to mind. If, say you have your `CombinedInterface` just so that it can be required for some particular function, like:

```
 void somefunction(CombinedInterface &object);
```

Your function requires a combined interface.

Make a small change:

```
 void somefunction(FirstInterface &first, SecondInterface &second);
```

and pass the same object as both parameters. You can pass `CompleteConcrete`, that implements both interfaces, without any changes to your class hierarchy. You could also have a template facade that makes it look like the function still takes one parameter:

```
template<typename T> void somefunction(T &&t)
{
    real_somefunction(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<T>(t));
}

void real_somefunction(FirstInterface &first, SecondInterface &second);
```

You can pretty much get rid of `CombinedInterface`, and simply pass any object that implements both interfaces to `somefunction()`, and your `real_somefunction()` will use one or the other parameter to invoke the appropriate interface.

Say you need to carry a pointer to an object that implements both interfaces?

```
class combined_pointer : public std::pair<FirstInterface *, SecondInterface *> {

public:
    template<typename T> combined_pointer(T *t)
            : std::pair<FirstInterface *, SecondInterface *>(t, t)
    {}
};
```

Just a starting point.

Comment: Good explanation and introduction of other solutions. I need to tell you why I really need CombinedInterface. I'm implementing a factory that returns a pointer to a CombinedInterface. This is why the trick of playing with two interfaces will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used virtual inheritance.

This compiled successfully with a warning, but I think it is ok.

```
class FirstInterface
{
    virtual int getId() const = 0;
};

class SecondInterface
{
    virtual void setId(int id) = 0;
};

class CombinedInterface : virtual public FirstInterface, public SecondInterface
{

};

class FirstConcrete : virtual public FirstInterface
{
    virtual int getId() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};


class CompleteConcrete : public CombinedInterface, public FirstConcrete
{
    virtual void setId(int id) { }
};


// warning: C4250:  inherits via dominance
CombinedInterface * combinedInterface = new CompleteConcrete();
```

Comment: Yes its OK. You can suppress warning C4250 for good. You *want* inheritance via dominance. I have no idea why MS compiler developers decided it's a bad thing.